# Run a Titanium Backup schedule from ADW Launcher's drawer

Tags: titanium-backup, adw.launcher

Is it possible to place a shortcut to Titanium Backup schedule in ADW Launcher's drawer?

I guess that one way would be to make a small app whose only job would be to launch TB's schedule by some kind of intent, but I couldn't find any information on intents provided by TB, and also making an app for such a simple task seems an overkill.

I am using CyanogenMod 7 (so it's rooted and so on...) and TB Pro.

Comment: What's the problem with TB's widget...

Comment: @SachinShekhar: You cannot put widgets into drawers AFAIK. And I don't want it on homescreen because it's not something I actually do frequently, so why should it take space there?

Comment: ADW launcher does support only apps in drawer, so you'll have to create app, as you said.

Comment: @SachinShekhar: Are there then other launchers similar to ADW which can do that?

Comment: No. I have checked it in all popular launchers. Drawers were never been designed for this. For custom shortcuts, you can always use Homescreen.

Comment: Are your 5 screens completely full?  I put less used apps/shortcuts far away from center screen.

Comment: @Chance: I use only one homescreen. I dislike the way multiple screens work--when I unlock the phone, I don't want to be in a situation where I need to look for a often used thing over 5 screens. But I like that when go to a drawer, it's just for one touch, so it automatically goes back to my only homescreen.

Comment: Hmm, interesting idea. Best I can thing of is if you use a folder to contain this shortcut, as well as other things.  It would take up one spot on your homescreen, but it could be a spot devoted to multiple tasks.

Answer (score 2):

Its not possible. App Drawer is designed to keep default shortcut of apps.. not custom shortcuts!
You can always use Homescreen to place custom shortcuts. I recommend you to use TB's widget. As ADW Launcher provides option to add multiple homescreens, space shouldn't be a problem.